# Removing arrays which are subsets of other arrays in Scala

Tags: arrays, scala, functional-programming, idioms

I have an array of array of integers. Like:

`val t1 = Array(Array(1, 2, 3), Array(2), Array(4, 5, 6), Array(5, 6))`

I want to remove the arrays that are subsets of another array. So, the result should be:

`Array(Array(1, 2, 3), Array(4, 5, 6))`

Ideally, these should be `Set`s, but in the context of my program, they are arrays, and I don't want to convert them to sets due to performance reasons.

I solved it this way in Scala, but I would like to know if there is a more elegant (and/or more efficient) way to do this:

```
def removeSubsets[T: ClassManifest](clusters: Array[Array[T]]) = {
    val sortedClusters = clusters.sortBy(-1 * _.length)
    sortedClusters.foldLeft(Array[Array[T]]()){ (acc, ele) =>
      val isASubset = acc.exists(arr => (ele diff arr).length == 0)
      if (isASubset) acc else acc :+ ele
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a typical union join problem (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure). This should give you a optimal solution. Idiomatically yours is fine too.

Comment: @Jatin -- His `Set`s are not necessarily disjoint though I guess.